# Does changing IP disturbs connection with server?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, proxy

I generally connect to my institute server using `ssh user@ipaddress`. It works fine.

Recently, I change IPv4 network address, network mask and Gateway in my Ubuntu system in order to get internet. I didn't change proxy settings on my system.

After modification, I cannot able to connect to the institute server using `ssh user@ipaddress`. The error is as follows

```
ssh: connect to host xxx.xx.xx.xx port xx: Connection timed out
```

Is it due to the change I did on my system or is it due to the issue from server side?

I also pinged to ip address using `ping ipaddress`. It is working properly

Comment: Both may possible. Ask your IT network administrator.

Comment: Second that^ For all we know your administrators may have firewall rules to simply drop SSH packets from outside a given set of IPs but still allow ICMP from anywhere.

Comment: You can test with some "public free ssh sftp servers" (google for it) and if the connection is OK, you can assume that your institute server is not accepting connections from your IP.